# Dragging an image to a specific location at the screen and alert if its the right location -Android-

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to develop an application where i can drag an image to a specific location in the screen and alert if its the right location , now the dragging part is done i just need to verify the location and show the alert when the image is in that specific location

Answer (score 1):

Get the `Rect` coord of the specific location and check if the dragged item coordinates clash with the location Rect coords. You can use `Rect.contains()` api for checking. If it returns true, you can show the alert.

```
if (locationRect.contains(drag.left, drag.top, drag.right, drag.bottom)) {
    // Show Alert dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have onTouch method in your code..

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction())
         {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
          .....
           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         int x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
         int y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();
        //if you want the alert when the image enters a square of (10,10)  (25,25),(10,25) and (25,10).. then 
        if(x_cord>=10 && x_cord<=25)
         {
        if(y_cord>10 && y_cord<25){<-- these cordinates work if the image you are moving is a square of side 15 .. so you can change accordingly..
         //alert here

           }
          }

 ......                       
  }
```